# Convert to uint32 from string in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

Here is the analog C#

```
BitConverter.ToUInt32(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash.Substring(i, 4)), 0)
```

is there a way to archive something similar to this in Javascript?

Comment: Pulling 4 characters off of a string will not necessarily result in 4 bytes. I would question why you would ever have 4 bytes (or an unsigned int) stored as a string through UTF-8 encoding in the first place. If you have bytes upfront and need to store as a string, it should have been base-64 or hex encoded.

Answer (score 1):

i think you might be wanting to grab the raw char codes from the string, in which case you don't even need to worry about unicode problems, keeping in mind that javascript uses two bytes per char anyway:

```
var str="✇ƒ";
var br=str.slice(0,2).split("")
       .map(function(a){return ("00000000000000000"+a.charCodeAt().toString(2))
       .slice(-16); })
var lng=parseInt(br.join(""),2);
var andBack = ( "00000000000000000" + lng.toString(2))
  .slice(-32)
  .split(/^(\w{16})/)
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map(function(a){return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a,2))})
  .join("");


alert([str, br, lng, andBack].join("\n"))

/* shows:
✇ƒ 
0010011100000111,0000000110010010
654770578
✇ƒ     
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. Simple bitshifts and add should do that:

```
// data[] contains 4 bytes representing an unsigned integer
// make sure to adjust for endiannes (may need to flip order of indexes)
var result = (data[0]<<24) + (data[1] << 16) + (data[2] << 8) + (data[3]);
```

Note that there is not enough precision in most implementations of JavaScript to properly hold all `UIint64`/`Int64` values.

Answer (score 0):

a simple line like

```
var my_int = +(value);
```

should usually do, other than that ceck out [parseint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Answer (score -1):

```
function utf8encode( str ) {
    var encoded = unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)),
        ret = new Uint8Array(encoded.length);

    for( var i = 0, len = encoded.length; i < len; ++i ) {
        ret[i] = encoded.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return ret;    
}

var uint32 = new Uint32Array(utf8encode(hash.substring(i, 4)).buffer)[0];
```

For example with:

```
var hash = "aosdasokda", i = 0;
```

`uint32` will be `1685286753` on little endian machine and  `1634693988` on big endian. This same inconsistency is present on [C# BitConverter as well](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx#code-snippet-2) and I assume must be reproduced.

Here is analog to `BitConverter.isLittleEndian`:

```
function isLittleEndian() {
    var v = new Uint16Array(1),
        r = new Uint8Array(v);
    v[0] = 0xFF00;
    return r[0] === 0x00;
}
```